# How to change the style of checkboxes when clicking on one of the list , inactive change the style?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change the style of checkboxes when clicking on one of the list , inactive change the style ? When you click the checkbox, the sf-option-active class is issued. How can css be changed by others ?

Initially, all the elements are highlighted, when you click on one checkbox others are dimmed

```html
<ul data-operator="or" class="list">
  <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-29" data-sf-count="19" data-sf-depth="0"><input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="tehobor" name="_sft_tip[]" id="sf-input-fc6224670cc95e4fdecf6cc456d08c36">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-fc6224670cc95e4fdecf6cc456d08c36">Name1</label></li>

  <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-30 sf-option-active" data-sf-count="6" data-sf-depth="0"><input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="konveiri" name="_sft_tip[]" checked="checked" id="sf-input-868176859db7cbdd316babead1c4a6ca"><label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-868176859db7cbdd316babead1c4a6ca">Name2</label></li>

  <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-31" data-sf-count="8" data-sf-depth="0"><input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="prolinii" name="_sft_tip[]" id="sf-input-080920625a50faa6f70e10891e88ebaa"><label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-080920625a50faa6f70e10891e88ebaa">Name3</label></li>

  <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-32" data-sf-count="4" data-sf-depth="0"><input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="neitrobor" name="_sft_tip[]" id="sf-input-df092a05d0048b1297780b8683077cb1"><label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-df092a05d0048b1297780b8683077cb1">Name4</label></li>
</ul>
```

**1:**

[image: image1]

**2:**

[image: image2]

Comment: Maybe you need radio buttons instead of checkboxes

Comment: radiobutton is not disabled when you click again..

Comment: The question is really unclear and the wording hard to read, "inactive change the style" for example? Please make the question more clear, if you want only one to be selectable, radiobutton is the right way to do it. You can disable the radiobuttons after selection if needed.

Comment: Added image. When all checkboxes are not active all are highlighted, when you click for example on 1 checkbox, the rest are dimmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with radio buttons is you cannot remove selection. If you do not want to use radio buttons, you can use this small jquery snippet here with checkboxes.

```js
$(".sf-input-checkbox").on("click", (e) => {
  if(e.target.checked) {
    $(".sf-input-checkbox").not($(e.target)).prop('checked', false);;
    $(".sf-label-checkbox").not($(e.target).next()).addClass("dimmed");
    $(e.target).next().removeClass("dimmed");
  } else {
    $(".sf-label-checkbox").removeClass("dimmed");
  }
});
```

```css
.dimmed {
  color: lightgray;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-operator="or" class="list">
  <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-29" data-sf-count="19" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox hidden" type="checkbox" value="tehobor" name="_sft_tip[]" id="sf-input-fc6224670cc95e4fdecf6cc456d08c36">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-fc6224670cc95e4fdecf6cc456d08c36">Name1</label>
  </li>

  <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-30 sf-option-active" data-sf-count="6" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox hidden" type="checkbox" value="konveiri" name="_sft_tip[]" id="sf-input-868176859db7cbdd316babead1c4a6ca">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-868176859db7cbdd316babead1c4a6ca">Name2</label>
  </li>

  <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-31" data-sf-count="8" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox hidden" type="checkbox" value="prolinii" name="_sft_tip[]" id="sf-input-080920625a50faa6f70e10891e88ebaa">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-080920625a50faa6f70e10891e88ebaa">Name3</label>
  </li>

  <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-32" data-sf-count="4" data-sf-depth="0">
    <input class="sf-input-checkbox hidden" type="checkbox" value="neitrobor" name="_sft_tip[]" id="sf-input-df092a05d0048b1297780b8683077cb1">
    <label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-df092a05d0048b1297780b8683077cb1">Name4</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're using checkbox AND JS for an HTML (radio !!! and css job)... This is not good at all

Comment: You cannot unselect a radio button and get original state (4 deselected). This solution allows for no selection. But I agree it could be done with vanillajs at least if OP does not use jquery library.

Comment: Good catch, i didnt saw the "unselect" state

Comment: Due to Ajax loading does not add a class, is it possible to somehow track the change of the sf-option-active class ?

Comment: You can use any data structure for storing changes. A basic object or a simple string for current input value checked could suffice. Just restore the checked value after ajax loading. `let currentVal = e.target.value;`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any JS for this. Instead you can just say in CSS:

For every label who are AFTER a checkbox: put it gray (`.moo + span`)

For every label who are AFTER a **CHECKED** checkbox: put it black (`.moo:checked + span`)

```css
.moo + span {
  color: #AAA;
}
.moo:checked + span {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name="moo" class="moo"><span>1111</span><br/>
<input type='radio' name="moo" class="moo"><span>2222</span><br/>
<input type='radio' name="moo" class="moo"><span>3333</span><br/>
<input type='radio' name="moo" class="moo"><span>4444</span>
```

With a little more code you can link the label to the checkbox and (why not) hiding the checkbox:

```css
.moo {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .moo + label {
      color: #AAA;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .moo:checked + label {
      color: #000;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type='radio' name="moo" id="c1" class="moo">
  <label for="c1">1111</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='radio' name="moo" id="c2" class="moo">
  <label for="c2">2222</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='radio' name="moo" id="c3" class="moo">
  <label for="c3">3333</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type='radio' name="moo" id="c4" class="moo">
  <label for="c4">4444</label>
</div>
```

**UPDATED with radio instead of checkbox**

Comment: OP wants to be able to deselect (reset to no selection)

Comment: You still cannot unselect and get back to initial phase (all 4 deselected)